# How to create an object depending on the last seven days?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, iteration

I have the following object:

```
[
    { createdAt: 6, numberofCreations: 3 },
    { createdAt: 7: numberofCreations: 2 },
    { createdAt: 2: numberofCreations: 6 },
    { createdAt: 3: numberofCreations: 3 },
    { createdAt: 4: numberofCreations: 1 },
    { createdAt: 1: numberofCreations: 2 },
    { createdAt: 5: numberofCreations: 1 }
]
```

Every number in the "createdAt" attribute represents a day of the week (1 for sunday, 2 for monday, 3 for tuesday, 4 for wednesday, 5 for thursday, 6 for friday and 7 for saturday). Every number in the "numberOfCreations" attribute represents how many elements were created that day of the week.

What I need is to rearrange this and create a new object where the ids are organized according to the last seven days, and also, arranged in orderly.

Meaning something like:

```
[2, 6, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2]
```

If you compare the second one with the first, you'll realize that this is organized depending on the day of the week.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question would be more well receive if you had shown what you have tried so far. It is generally a forum for answering a problem you are unable to solve, not for solving the homework for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You will want to use a custom [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and then after that use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the values you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, you could sort the array on `createdAt` property and the use `map` function to retrieve just `numberofCreations` attribute. Something like:

```js
let input = [
    { createdAt: 6, numberofCreations: 3 },
    { createdAt: 7, numberofCreations: 2 },
    { createdAt: 2, numberofCreations: 6 },
    { createdAt: 3, numberofCreations: 3 },
    { createdAt: 4, numberofCreations: 1 },
    { createdAt: 1, numberofCreations: 2 },
    { createdAt: 5, numberofCreations: 1 }
]

input.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a.createdAt - b.createdAt;
})

console.log(input.map(el => el.numberofCreations))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows **array** of objects. By the way, inside your objects you mistake colon with comma.

```
let array = [
  { createdAt: 6, numberofCreations: 3 },
  { createdAt: 7, numberofCreations: 2 },
  { createdAt: 2, numberofCreations: 6 },
  { createdAt: 3, numberofCreations: 3 },
  { createdAt: 4, numberofCreations: 1 },
  { createdAt: 1, numberofCreations: 2 },
  { createdAt: 5, numberofCreations: 1 }
];
```

To order elements of the array you can use **sort** method. "a" is the first element of the list, "b" is the next one. Because you want to order by createdAt, so you'll compare **a.createdAt** with **b.createdAt**.

```
array.sort((a, b) => a.createdAt - b.createdAt);

console.log(array);
[{ createdAt: 1, numberofCreations: 2 },
{createdAt: 2, numberofCreations: 6},
{createdAt: 3, numberofCreations: 3},
{createdAt: 4, numberofCreations: 1},
{createdAt: 5, numberofCreations: 1},
{createdAt: 6, numberofCreations: 3},
{createdAt: 7, numberofCreations: 2}]
```